# Immigrant visa being refused because i am 23years old

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

we had our immigration visa interview on the 28th of feb. and my chacha ( fathers brother ) had his interview on the 22nd of feb which got issued. In our case my parents got their visa issued , but me and my brother aged 23 and 27 did not. Can please someone help me with what should be done? Its showing refused. We are a joint family and we stay together and it is not possible for my parents to leave us alone here in india. Also we are still dependent on them.

Comment: You will have been given some documentation regarding your refusal. Please post that here with personal details blacked out so that we can see exactly what you've been told.

Comment: Questions about immigration belong on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: At 23 you are an adult by US law and hence your statement `and it is not possible for my parents to leave us alone here in india. Also we are still dependent on them` does not hold with USA immigration. There is a category for `Family Fourth Preference (F4), Brothers and sisters of U.S. citizens, and their spouses and minor children, provided the U.S. citizens are at least 21 years of age. (65,000)` You do not fall into this category because **you are over 21**. Case closed. Do not go and pay any lawyer or agent. Nobody can help you, even if your friend is Donald Trump he cannot help you.